# In VS2012 how do I filter the Object Browser to display objects in my Project?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

In VS2012 how do I filter the Object Browser to display objects accessible from my Project?

As far as I can make out from the UI it can be configured to show either

1) Everything installed on the machine.
2) A manually selected subset of everything installed on the machine.
3) Everything referenced by the entire Solution.

So where is the most useful view of all, namely the view of everything referenced by the current Project?

The MSDN even states that you can use it to view what can be referenced by the Project

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/exy1facf%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

"The Object Browser lets you select and examine the namespaces, classes, methods, and other programming symbols available for use in your project."

But I can't see how to do it.

Comment: As far as I can see you can't do this! You can edit the Custom Component Set to only include a single project, but there isn't a "current project" option, just the entire solution or some pre-defined subset.

Comment: If you edit the Custom Component Set to include a single project, then the Object Browser only shows objects _defined_ in the Project, it does not show objects that can be _referenced_ by the Project.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Class View (Ctrl + Shift + C)` to see the references available per project.

Look in the `Projects References` section of each project in the Class View.

**Example: Class Library in Solution**

Here, I am looking at the `System.Collections` classes.

[image]

**Example: WPF Project in Solution**

Here I am looking a the `System.Diagnostics` classes

[image]

To view the class in **Object Browser**, right click and choose, "Browse Definition".

[image]

Comment: That's a useful workaround. I'll try using that, thanks. Shame it doesn't seem to be possible to hide the treeview in the Object Browser itself though.